# Use Meteor Match and Regex to check strings

Tags: regex, meteor, match

I'm checking an array of strings for a specific combination of patterns. I'm having trouble using Meteor's Match function and regex literal together. I want to check if the second string in the array is a url.

```
addCheck = function(line) {

    var firstString = _.first(line);

    var secondString = _.indexOf(line, 1);

    console.log(secondString);

    var urlRegEx = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/g;


    if ( firstString == "+" && Match.test(secondString, urlRegEx) === true )  {

        console.log( "detected: + | line = " + line )

    } else {
        // do stuff if we don't detect a 
        console.log( "line = " + line );

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: secondString.match(urlRegEx);

Comment: urlRegEx.test(secondString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Match.test](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/match_test) is used to test the structure of a variable. For example: "it's an array of strings, or an object including the field *createdAt*", etc.

[RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) on the other hand, is used to test if a given string matches a regular expression. That looks like what you want.

Try something like this instead:

```js
if ((firstString === '+') && urlRegEx.test(secondString)) {
  ...
}
```